# Toggle multiple divs one by one jquery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

What i am trying to do is toggle between different div's. It's kinda hard to explain but i'll give it a try.

---

When the page loads there would be div that is visible and 4 with display:none. And there would be a menu. link 1 would show the first div and hide all others. Then when clicking link 2 the div that is visible will hide and div2 would show. When clicking link 3 the div that is visible will hide and div3 would show and so on.
Basically only one div shown at a time.

---

I wrote this but it works only when there are 2 divs.

```
$(function () {
  $('#link').click(function () { 
    $('#div1, #div2').toggle();
  });
});
```

but this would only show the hidden div and hide the one that is shown.

Okay, i did it and found out that it can be done much easier. Here's what i did. It's not very elegant but it works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.slidingDiv').hide();
  $('.show_hide').show();

  $('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
    $('.slidingDiv2').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv3').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv4').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv5').hide('slow');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.slidingDiv2').hide();
  $('.show_hide2').show();

  $('.show_hide2').click(function () {
    $('.slidingDiv2').slideToggle();
    $('.slidingDiv').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv3').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv4').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv5').hide('slow');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.slidingDiv3').hide();
  $('.show_hide3').show();

  $('.show_hide3').click(function () {
    $('.slidingDiv3').slideToggle();
    $('.slidingDiv').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv2').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv4').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv5').hide('slow');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.slidingDiv4').hide();
  $('.show_hide4').show();

  $('.show_hide4').click(function () {
    $('.slidingDiv4').slideToggle();
    $('.slidingDiv').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv2').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv3').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv5').hide('slow');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slidingDiv5').hide();
  $('.show_hide5').show();

  $('.show_hide5').click(function () {
    $('.slidingDiv5').slideToggle();
    $('.slidingDiv').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv2').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv3').hide('slow');
    $('.slidingDiv4').hide('slow');
  });
});
```

And `<a href="#"  class="show_hide"><span class="nav">link</span></a>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define your links as follows:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div1">link 1</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div2">link 2</a>

<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
```

Then you can make things easy: http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ymj/.

```
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding selector from data-toggle
  $("div").hide();
  $(selector).show();
});
```

Comment: If im not wrong this would show the next div, right? What if i click on the fourth link and then the third one?

Comment: Okay, i tried doing it, i failed. I even copy pasted all of the content from jsfiddle and still i can't get it to work. Any clue?

Comment: @user1623157: Just to make sure - the jsFiddle works and is what you want?

Comment: this is great @pimvdb, tysir

Answer (score 3):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbbhL/)

HTML:

```
<a href='#' class='link'>link 1</a>
<div id='#div1' class='panel active'> Visible </div>
<a href='#' class='link'>link 2</a>
<div id='#div1' class='panel'> Visible </div>
<a href='#' class='link'>link 3</a>
<div id='#div1' class='panel'> Visible </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.panel { display:none; }
div.panel.active { display:block; }
```

JS:

```
$(function()   {
    $(".link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.panel:visible').hide();
        $(this).next('div.panel').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a link between the ID of the link and the div:

```
$(".link").click(function() {

    var idIndex = parseInt(this.attr("id")); // Extracts the number of the ID
    $(".divs").hide();
    $("#div" + idIndex).show();

});
```

So you basically hide all the divs first and then display the one that corresponds to the ID that was clicked. This is not noticeable for the user. So instead of toggling based on current status. Think of it as toggling all off, and then toggle the one you want on.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to toggle n number of divs'.

```
**$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
          var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding selector from data-toggle
          //alert(selector);
          $(selector).fadeIn(1000);
          $(selector).siblings().hide();
        });
    });**
```