# Toggling specific paragraphs using jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to get jquery function to work on table rows. I am basing my solution on the [following stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236629/toggle-multiple-divs-one-by-one-jquery), however whenever I click on the expand link nothing seems to happen. I tried to debug the javascript code but it doesn't to reach it.

Here is the HTML code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style>       td { white-space: pre }       p { display: none }   </style>   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
       var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
       $("p").hide();
       $(selector).show();
   });   
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" style="border-collapse: collapse">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="confluenceTh"></th>
        <th class="confluenceTh">a1</th>
        <th class="confluenceTh">a2</th>
        <th class="confluenceTh">a3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>  
  <td class="confluenceTd"><a href ="#" data-toggle="#content0">Expand</button></td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b1</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b2</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b3</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td colspan = "4" class="confluenceTd">
<p id="content1" class="expanding-content">val1</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
  <td class="confluenceTd"><a href ="#" data-toggle="#content1">Expand</button></td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c1</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c2</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td colspan = "4" class="confluenceTd">
<p id="content1" class="expanding-content">val2</p>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: wrap the code in a document ready statement

Comment: Of course!!! so foolish!

Comment: @madalinivascu could you please post your solution so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. wrap the code in `$(document).ready`
2. place it after your body tag close at the bottom of the file ([benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document))

Your code also had mismatch of target element.

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle"); // get corresponding element
  $("p").hide();
  $(selector).show();
});
```

```css
.expanding-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="confluenceTh"></th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">a1</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">a2</th>
      <th class="confluenceTh">a3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="confluenceTd"><a href="#" data-toggle="#content1">Expand</button></td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b1</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b2</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b3</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td colspan = "4" class="confluenceTd">
<p id="content1" class="expanding-content">val1</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
  <td class="confluenceTd"><a href ="#" data-toggle="#content2">Expand</button></td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c1</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c2</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td colspan = "4" class="confluenceTd">
<p id="content2" class="expanding-content">val2</p>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap the code in a document ready statement

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is your jquery selector, you are targeting your links wrongly, try this instead:

```
    <script>
    $("a[data-toggle=*]").on("click", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
       var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
       $("p").hide();
       $(selector).show();
   });   
   </script>
```

That way you will target all A tags, with a data-toggle with any value inside it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way:

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ymj/657/)**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" style="border-collapse: collapse">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="confluenceTh"></th>
        <th class="confluenceTh">a1</th>
        <th class="confluenceTh">a2</th>
        <th class="confluenceTh">a3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>  
  <td class="confluenceTd"><a href ="#" data-toggle="#content0">Expand</button></td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b1</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b2</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">b3</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td colspan = "4" class="confluenceTd">
<p id="content0" class="expanding-content">val1</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
  <td class="confluenceTd"><a href ="#" data-toggle="#content1">Expand</button></td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c1</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c2</td>
  <td class="confluenceTd">c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>  
<td colspan = "4" class="confluenceTd">
<p id="content1" class="expanding-content">val2</p>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click","a[data-toggle]", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
  $("p").hide();
  $(selector).show();
});
```