# How to toggle multiple div's in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236629/toggle-multiple-divs-one-by-one-jquery) solution, it works fine on static pages but for some reason doesn't work on angular.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6q5xnmL9

My html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #f3f7fa">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light d-flex" >        
     <a data-toggle="#action" class="nav-item">QUICK ACTION</a>
     <a data-toggle="#basic" class="nav-item">BASIC</a>
     <a data-toggle="#notes" class="nav-item">NOTES</a>
     <a data-toggle="#deals" class="nav-item">DEALS</a>
     <a data-toggle="#reminder" class="col-auto nav-item">REMINDER</a>
    </nav>
</div>

//div's to be toggled
<div id="action" class="actions mod-row">...</div>
<div id="basic" class="actions mod-row">...</div>
<div id="notes" class="actions mod-row">...</div>
<div id="deals" class="actions mod-row">...</div>
<div id="reminder" class="actions mod-row">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.actions:not(#action) {
  display: none;
}
```

solution given in above link:

```
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
    var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
    $(".actions").hide();
    $(selector).show();
 }
  );
```

However, using this code angular was showing error :

> parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type

so I modified the code to:

```
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e:Event) {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
        var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
        $(".actions").hide();
        $(selector).show();
        }
      );
```

also tried:

```
 $("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function() {
        this.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
        var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
        $(".actions").hide();
        $(selector).show();
        }
      );
```

And lastly I even removed the prevention navigation line of code.
I am not sure if these were correct but all of these modifications removed the error but the toggle still didn't work.
What am I missing?

Comment: How your html looks like? Have you tried binding event to non dynamic content (`$(document).on('a.toggle ', 'click', ...)`)?

Comment: Would you like to hide by css class?

Comment: I have looked JSFIDDLE. It's like a navigation so is routing not good?

Comment: Do you really need to use jQuery here? Angular has really well developed template system. If you don't use above code with Angular, you can edit your tags.

Comment: I am new to angular, so not really familiar with a lot of its stuff. Could provide any link to learn how to do this with angular templates or give an alternate solution.

Comment: @Justinas I have added my HTML component to the question. And I just tried this line too it still didn't work.

Comment: Avoid binding to CSS selectors like that using jQuery if you can. You have the `[hidden]` property on each element, which you can use to drive their hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not a static page, you can't use jQuery like you use it on a "normal" website. If you chose to use angular then you should also do everything "the angular way"

There are different ways to do this, but in short: You handle the state of your visible tabs / sections in your component by defining a click event on your a-tag:

```
<a href="#action" (click)="toggleNav(e)" class="nav-item">QUICK ACTION</a>
```

In your tabs / sections you add a condition for when this section should be handled

```
<div id="action" [hidden]="shownDiv != 'action'"> This div is hidden if shownDiv variable is not 'action' ... So if it's value is 'action' it will be shown </div>
```

In your components ts file you handle the click event and also set the `shownDiv` variable set in the `[hidden]` parameter accordingly.

```
toggleNav(e: Event) {
 e.preventDefault;
 this.shownDiv = e.target.href.substring(1); // href is #action, we just want action, so we remove the first character
}
```

you should also set the shownDiv to a sensible default value so that the tab you want opened first is shown by default, something like this:

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
  shownDiv = 'action'; // default value
```